# Perl Error with Log::Log4perl::Appender::File

Tags: multithreading, perl, log4perl

I am trying to build application with the help of Perl. The application consists of [`Thread::Pool`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Pool) and [`Log4Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl) packages from perl.

When i exclude package `Thread::Pool` logging works.
But when i include it it gives me error as following:

```
ERROR: can't load appenderclass 'Log::Log4perl::Appender::File'
Could not find file for 'Log::Log4perl::Appender::File' at C:/Perl/site/lib/load.pm line 214.
```

Working Code :

```
# use Thread::Pool;
use Log::Log4perl;

my $log_conf = 'LoggingConfiguration.conf';
Log::Log4perl::init($log_conf);
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger();
$logger->info(" Info Msg ");
```

But if i remove comment as

```
use Thread::Pool;
```

it gives above error

What is the exact reason for this to happen? How to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you *installed* `Log::Log4perl::Appender::File`?

Comment: Yes i installed its working correctly without Thread::Pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From some searching around, it appears that there are problems with Thread::Pool's use of the `use load` pragma:

From the [Thread::Pool bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=81267):

> When creating object under perl 5.8.8, adding 'use Thread::Pool' is causing issues when items 
>   are being blessed. Specifically, in many instances code that normally returns values and that are 
>   then blessed show up as null. Removing the 'use load' pragma from Thread::* fixes the issue.

[Thread::Pool on cpanratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Thread-Pool):

> This module is indeed convenient, but in my opinion there are some serious problems with it. 
>   [ ... ]
>   Second, this module is using 'use load' which causes Log::Log4perl to malfunction. That is certainly one evil heisenbug. It was only because I found a Czech comment in this source file (http://w2c.martin.majlis.cz/w2c/doc-gen/crawler_8pl_source.html - link broken) that it didn't take me days of debugging.

[Thread::Pool issues with Log4Perl on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1029507) - unresolved, but answers include:

> Do not use Thread::Pool. It is buggy. Switch to [Thread::Queue](http://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Pool::Queue). (OP's response: problems persisted with Thread::Queue)
>
> You also might try [Thread::Pool::Simple](http://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Pool::Simple). I've had better luck with that than Thread::Pool.

So the consensus is either try removing `use load` from Thread::Pool, or use a different module.